# Domain & subdomain canonical URL

Tags: seo, subdomain, canonical-link, canonicalization

I have a website where content on few subdomains is the same as on main domain. The reason for this is that I run an affiliate program.

For example affiliate1.mydomain.com has same content as mydomain.com (except different style).

What I would like to know what should be canonical url on my affiliate subdomains. Should I put all links to start with http://mydomain.com (same as on main domain)?

Note: all internal links on affilate1.mydomain.com point to affilate1.mydomain.com/something-here/.

Please suggest me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If all of your sites are merely "Spun" You might think more about building ONE great site vs a bunch of them and you'll be much better off

Comment: The whole point of multiple sites is that those subdomains would look exactly like the affiliate main site, so users would feel more at home.